# Unexpected Callback Behavior in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I expect the following code to run as follows:
1) iterate through the for loop until complete.
2) Execute the callback function

Instead, it executes the callback after each iteration. Is it a scope issue? Am I misunderstanding control flow of callbacks?

```
function flipPages(direction,n,duration,callback){
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        setTimeout(function() { $('#flipbook').turn(direction);}, ((i+1) * duration));
    }
    callback;
}

flipPages("next",4,1000,flipPages("previous",4,2000));
```

Comment: you can't pass parameters to a callback before it has been passed as a callback. What you're doing is immediately executing "previous" and then executing "next". Also, you never executed `callback`, you're missing `()`

Comment: you are misunderstanding setTimeout I think... the flow is probably as follow : 1) iterates through the loop, initiate timeouts 2) launch callback 3) launch all the method calls now the timeout is over

Comment: You should try with this, as pointed out by @KevinB flipPages("next",4,1000, function() {flipPages("previous",4,2000)});

Comment: callback is getting executed too early, you should place it inside a `setTimeout` aswell, `n+1*duration` or similar delay.

Comment: Kevin B's answers gave me the solution I needed. The method I'm calling doesn't return anything, so I needed to set up a set of calls that aren't in a queue. The n+1*duration was the ticket for that. I appreciate others helping me understand setTimeout better.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all these relevant comments, I guess you wanted to do something like this :

```
function flipPages(direction, n, duration){
    for(var i = 0, l = n; i < n; i++){
        setTimeout(function() { 
            $('#flipbook').turn(direction);
            if (!(--n)) {
                flipPages({
                    // direction switch
                    next: "previous",
                    previous: "next"
                }[direction], n, duration);
            }
        }, ((i + 1) * duration));
    }
}

flipPages("next", 4, 1000);
```

Updated : no need to use a callback, use `flipPages` directly.